# .Net 4.5 : Should I use IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I used to use `IDataErrorInfo` in my MVVM/WPF applications. Now after `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is available in .Net 4.5 is it better to replace `IDataErrorInfo` or continue the old way using `IDataErrorInfo`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are a number of improvements in `INotifyDataErrorInfo` (in particular, it's support for multiple, dynamically changing error messages per object/property) that make it superior to the previous interface. But the biggest difference is that it's asynchronous. You now have to fire the `ErrorsChanged` event whenever the error state changes.

If you are implementing an application in .NET 4.5 that targets devices running Windows 8, you should strongly consider using the new interface. Asynchronous-style programming is the "intended model" for such applications, particularly if you include RT-devices. It's not that much more complex to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` over `IDataErrorInfo`, so there's not really a downside.

That doesn't mean you should go retrofit all your existing applications, though; again, it depends on your target. If you're trying to upgrade an existing application to be RT-compatible, you should probably swap in the new error handling code. Otherwise, no need to change what works.