# WPF checkbox binding doesn't work after adding Bindinggroup NotifyOnValidationError

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a dialog implement using MVVM, it works fine with bindings etc. so checking a checkbox is updated in the ViewModel.

However, I have now implemented validation using the WPF `Binding.ValidationRules` and added a `BindingGroup`to my `stackpanel` on the dialog:

```
<StackPanel.BindingGroup>
  <BindingGroup NotifyOnValidationError="True">
  </BindingGroup>
</StackPanel.BindingGroup>
```

So I can catch all validation errors. But adding the `BindingGroup` also means that my binding to the ViewModel doesn't work anymore for the checkboxes. 
Anyone have a good idea why the checkboxes suddenly doesn't work, but my textbox's still do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for validation with MVVM go ahead with INotifyDataErrorInfo.

The best practice is to implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface (if you are on .NET 4.5) or the IDataErrorInfo interface. [Please refer to the blog post about data validation in WPF for more information and code samples:](http://blog.micic.ch/net/easy-mvvm-example-with-inotifypropertychanged-and-inotifydataerrorinfo)

Comment: Is that best practice or common practice? Considering that most of the implementationer i have seen doing this is using one big switch case in the code, then no thank you. Wpf does support it in XAML, hence the binding group.

Comment: please go thru the link given. This is the best practice. and supports MVVM.

Comment: Sorry, I confused your suggestion with the older IDataErrorInfo where the examples I found on the internet mostly consisted of large switch  case or if statements. I see that your suggestion is very valid and is the proper way to do it, if it was possible for me to go the .NET 4.5 way. But we are still at .NET 4.0..

Comment: Hi, you can think about IDataErrorInfo if you are still in .Net 4.0, here is link
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx

you can have a comparison with this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402840/net-4-5-should-i-use-idataerrorinfo-or-inotifydataerrorinfo

Comment: Well you get the answer, I reverted to this solution after looking at the above link. It is a very nice implementation example considering all the other examples i have seen with the big if else or switch case in the "public string this[string columnName]" method

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `CommitEdit` on the `BindingGroup`:

```
if (stackPanel1.BindingGroup.CommitEdit())
{
    stackPanel1.BindingGroup.BeginEdit();
}
```

Maybe, have a `Button` somewhere on the `UserControl` that does this in the click event handler, or in the `Checked` event handler of the `CheckBox`?

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at that. But still strange that a textbox binding works I think.